# Canvas Html 5 Resize center

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using html5 and canvas to resize an image on the client side.
 I have two functions, clientresize and loadcanvas.

Client resize uses the filereader to get image and loadcanvas function crops and centers the image from a data URL. Can anyone point what I'm doing wrong in the function loadcanvas() because the dataURL is a black blank image.

```
function clientresize(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result;
        img.onload = function () {
        var min_height = 500;
            var min_width = 500;
            var max_width = 600;
            var max_height = 600;
            var tempW = img.width;
            var tempH = img.height;
            var aspect_ratio = 1;
            if (tempW > tempH) {
                //scale down using height for aspect ratio
                if (tempH > max_height) {
                    var aspect_ratio = tempH / max_width
                    tempH = tempH / aspect_ratio;
                    tempW = tempW / aspect_ratio;
                }
                //scale up using height for aspect ratio
                else if ((tempH >= min_height) && (tempW >= max_width)) {
                    var aspect_ratio = max_height / tempH;
                    tempH = tempH * aspect_ratio;
                    tempW = tempW * aspect_ratio;
                }
            } else {

                if (tempW > max_width) {
                    var aspect_ratio = tempW / max_width
                    tempH = tempH / aspect_ratio;
                    tempW = tempW / aspect_ratio;
                } else if ((tempW >= min_width) && (tempH >= max_height)) {
                    var aspect_ratio = max_width / tempW;
                    tempH = tempH * aspect_ratio;
                    tempW = tempW * aspect_ratio;
                }
            }

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvas.width = tempW;
            canvas.height = tempH;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            loadcanvas(dataURL, tempW, tempH, max_width, max_height, canvas)
        }

        function loadcanvas(dataURL, tempW, tempH, max_width, max_height, canvas) {
            var copy = document.createElement('canvas');
            copy.id = "uploadedcanvas";
            copy.width = max_width;
            copy.height = max_height;
            var copyctx = copy.getContext("2d");
            var sx = (tempW - max_width) / 2
            var sy = (tempH - max_height) / 2
            var imgcopy = new Image();
            imgcopy.onload = function () {
                copyctx.drawImage(this, sx, sy, 600, 600, 0, 0, 600, 600);
            }
            imgcopy.src = dataURL;
            var m = copy.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

when I get the value of m the image is just a blank image. I would however want to crop and center on a white background. Any pointers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: 1) did you check that the image was loaded by drawing it to a visible canvas ? could be a cross origin issue.  2) i guess you want to call toDataURL inside the onload handler of the image.

Comment: @GameAlchemist It does indeed get loaded. The problem is it doesn't convert copy to data url in time before it draws the image.

Comment: so did you read my second point ?